# Conda environment setting os variable for Plaid Python Quickstart

Tags: python, git, environment-variables, plaid

I'm setting up (or attempting to) set up Plaid Python to automate my personal finance. I'm running into issues with the startup script below. (From [here](https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#introduction)).

```
git clone https://github.com/plaid/quickstart.git
cd quickstart/python

# For virtualenv users
# virtualenv venv
# source venv/bin/activate

pip install -r requirements.txt

# Start the Quickstart with your API keys from the Dashboard
# https://dashboard.plaid.com/account/keys
PLAID_CLIENT_ID='CLIENT_ID' \
PLAID_SECRET='SECRET' \
PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY='PUBLIC_KEY' \
PLAID_ENV='sandbox' \
PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions \
python server.py
# Go to http://localhost:5000
```

So far I cloned the repo and created my conda environment, but when I try to set the keys variables with my API keys using

```
PLAID_CLIENT_ID='mykeygoeshere' \
```

, I get

```
PLAID_CLIENT_ID is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I believe I need to set the environment variable somehow in my conda environment but I am wondering what is the proper way to do it. I'm reading that you can set it using the line below, but will that affect just my virtual environment or my whole OS registry?

```
set NEWVAR=SOMETHING
```

Answer (score 0):

`varname=envvalue command` is a Unix shell syntax. So either you have to run the command in git-bash terminal or you need to adapt it to your OS command line interpreter.

The OS seems to be Windows, right? `set` is the command. It affects only the current terminal. To avoid repeating multiple commands in an every new terminal put them into a batch file.